# Python Pandas mark all but one specific duplicate row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that has already been reduced to duplicates only and sorted.
Duplicates are identified by column "HASH" and then sorted by "HASH" and "SIZE"

```
df_out['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(['HASH'], keep=False) #keep=False: mark all duplicates as true
df_out = df_out.ix[(df_out['is_duplicated'] == True)] #Keep only duplicate records
df_out = df_out.sort_values(['HASH', 'SIZE'], ascending=[True, False]) #Sort by "HASH", then by "SIZE"
```

Result:

```
HASH  SIZE  is_duplicated
1      5     TRUE
1      3     TRUE
1      2     TRUE
9      7     TRUE
9      5     TRUE
```

I would like to add 2 more columns. 
First column would identify rows of data with the same "HASH" by an ID.
First set of rows with the same "HASH" would be 1, next set would be 2, etc...

Second column would mark the a single row in each group that has the largest "SIZE"

```
HASH  SIZE ID   KEEP
1      5   1    TRUE
1      3   1    FALSE
1      2   1    FALSE
9      7   2    TRUE
9      5   2    FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use dicts and list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,9,9],[5,3,2,7,5]]).T
df.columns = ['HASH','SIZE']

hash_dict = dict(zip(df.HASH.unique(),range(1,df.HASH.nunique()+1)))
df['ID'] = [hash_dict[k] for k in df.HASH]

max_dict = dict(df.groupby('HASH')['SIZE'].max())
df['KEEP'] = [True if b==max_dict[a] else False for a,b in zip(df.HASH,df.SIZE)]
```